# Nested awaits in C# impact on performance

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

I am exposing a method in  Api that is expecting a 500 hits from per second.

I have made all the API's as async to be responsive.
there could be  multiple database calls in each request, should those be async or sync.

My point is nested awaits let's say 3 levels.
In such scenario, will it improve performance or the context switching badly affect the performance.
I have searched enough but i am getting more confuse.
There should be some rule of thumbs that i want to follow.

Also on the bottom, the database call is sync call that i couldn't do much of as already written.

Comment: There is only 1 rule of thumb... benchmark, since any line of code can be a problem and you haven't suplied any ,who knows, also why would your dB call be sync...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of `await`s isn't usually important. There are some things you can do (e.g., using `ValueTask<T>` instead of `Task<T>`) if you find the performance unsuitable.

However, the big performance problem is here:

> on the bottom, the database call is sync call

If the low-level call is synchronous, then you'll likely have scalability problems. If the current code is doing "async over sync" (e.g., `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`), then that would be a problem. Either change the code to be "async all the way" (i.e., make the db call asynchronous) and accept the additional work that needs to be done, or change it to be synchronous all the way and accept the limited scalability of a synchronous solution.

Comment: if the nature of the database calls is fire and forget. Like just an update and don't return anything from it, in such case will the async wrapper around the sync database call give any benefit.?

Comment: @Bezhas Let's take take step back... rather than give examples without appropriate context and guessing,  there is this guy I know of that tells you all about the async and await pattern and has some great blog posts you should read ;)

Comment: @TheGeneral I have been reading his blog since 4 hours. I know he is the best in THE Async Await

Comment: @Bezhas: Are you sure you want fire-and-forget for your database updates? "Fire and forget" literally means you *don't care* if the operation actually happens or not, and "database updates" sounds kind of important to me. I usually recommend not returning early, but if you do need to [there's a well-established pattern to follow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, you mean that if there is a sync method in nested methods then there is no gain in scalability and performance. Currently now adays, all the methods in rest apis are by default marked as async.

Comment: @Bezhas: Not if it uses `Task.Run` to run the synchronous code.

Comment: @StephenCleary,I am not using Task. Run but the call in a nested method is a sync call

Comment: @Bezhas: I don't know what your code is doing. Do you have an `async` without an `await`?

Comment: An async method is having two operations 1.Sync call to database  and 2 an operation which is awaited. And returned. There is no Task.Run but an async method

Comment: @Bezhas: Ah. In that case the awaited operation would give you some scalability benefits. It would just be even better if the db was asynchronous, too.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the asynchronous programming (i.e. the use of coroutines) is not to introduce performance gain, but to improve the the computing resources when you are not using them. Every `await` you use, introduce a "check point", where the execution might be "suspended".

While your logical code is "suspended", the underlying thread is not sleeping like it happens in the synchronous execution model. This is vital for (web)service-based APIs where you can have multiple concurrent requests: when a request is waiting for IO (both network or local), the underlying thread can still progress another request, thus improving the overall throughput of the **whole** service. Each request does not gain any benefit; truly, it gains a little overhead as the compiler rewrites your code into a state machine to handle the "suspension" and "resume".

For this reason, besides from benchmarking, you should choose the granularity of your analysis.

Comment: yes, I understand a little bit that any method that is async actually at compile time becomes a class (statemachine) where await becomes checkpoints. My point to ask is doing a lot of awaits in nested call like A() => B()=> C()=>D(). Will the context switching cost performance? may be i am worng but there could be 16 different thread completing a method in above case. Looking for your answer

Comment: Switching the context is indeed expensive, but "how much is expensive" cannot be evaluated on paper, you have to benchmark your code. Also, keep in mind, that suspension is not deterministic: suppose you ask a row to a `DataReader`, if the components reads 10 lines ahead, you will be likely suspended the first time, and then, the next 9 rows you'll have the value locally, thus no need for being suspended. There are many factors to consider. My best guess, is to implement both the versions, and then measure them (calling them at least 10K-100K times)